# Powershell StreamReader ReadLine / ReadToEnd reads same line multiple times

Tags: powershell, streamreader, powershell-3.0

I have a function to retrieve the last n lines of a text file (in this case a log file):

```
function Get-Tail([object]$reader, [int]$count = 10) {

    $lineCount = 0
    [long]$pos = $reader.BaseStream.Length - 1

    while($pos -gt 0)
    {    
        $reader.BaseStream.position=$pos

        if ($reader.BaseStream.ReadByte() -eq 10)
        {
            $lineCount++
            if ($lineCount -ge $count) { break }
        } 
        $pos--
    } 

    # tests for file shorter than requested tail
    if ($lineCount -lt $count -or $pos -ge $reader.BaseStream.Length - 1) {
        $reader.BaseStream.Position=0
    } else {
        $reader.BaseStream.Position = $pos+1
    }

    # debug
    write-host $reader.readtoend()

    [....]
}
```

Trapping at Write-Host I find that $pos is 166 (i.e. well before EndOfStream).

The output from this is:

```
2013/02/23 03:39:13 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory \\[redacted]
The system cannot find the file specified. -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Sat Feb 23 03:39:13 2013

   Source : [redacted]
     Dest : [redacted]

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /FFT /V /TS /FP /NDL /TEE /S /E /COPY:DATS /SECFIX /PURGE /MIR /B /NP /XO /XN /XC /R:0 /W:0 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2013/02/23 03:39:13 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory \\[redacted]
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So, the last two full lines are repeated. I have tried flushing the streamreader first, makes no odds.

This is a bit confusing. I assume I am making a schoolboy error, but can't work out which one. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

If you can move away from the StreamReader than you can use this simple command to retrieve the last x number of lines in a text file.

```
Get-Content C:\example.txt -Tail 10
```

Comment: I was using that before, but it's too slow and causes out of memory errors when handling some of the logs (which run to > 200MB in some cases). Later code parses the log. So I really think I do need to fix it using StreamReader.